# Bitlocker File Encryption

Tags: windows, encryption

I found out that Bitlocker is available only in Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise.
I'm using Windows 7 Professional x64 and I'd like to encrypt one of my hard disks. Is it possible to "implement" this program also on my system? Or maybe you know other ways to do it similarly instead of using bitlocker ?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org).

> Main Features:
>
> - Creates a **virtual encrypted disk** within a file and mounts it as a real disk.
> - Encrypts an **entire partition or storage device** such as USB flash drive or hard drive.
> - Encrypts a **partition or drive where Windows is installed** (pre-boot authentication).
> - Encryption is **automatic**, **real-time** (on-the-fly) and **transparent**.
> - Parallelization and pipelining allow data to be read and written as fast as if the drive was not encrypted.
>
>   Encryption can be hardware-accelerated on modern processors.
> - Provides **plausible deniability**, in case an adversary forces you to reveal the password:
>     **Hidden volume** (steganography) and **hidden operating system**.

Answer (score 1):

Bitlocker is restricted to Ultimate and Enterprise.  A quick search on full disk encryption and some research could help you.  A comparison of disk encryption software can be found here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software

Truecrypt is a good choice, just create a partition on a disk of your choice and encrypt the entire thing, or the free space of your hard drive, there are many options with TC.  Going over the many algorithms and benefits of each is probably beyond the scope of this thread, possibly a good topic for the folks at

https://security.stackexchange.com/